# Implementing decimal factorial in python

Tags: python

I've been trying to implement math functions without the help of `math` module.
I used a simple recursive function for factorial:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        f = n * factorial(n - 1)
        return f
```

But recently I found out about the gamma function (which is used to find factorial of decimal numbers). How do I implement it in python?

Comment: Not easily. The gamma function doesn't have a closed form; it's just an integral that you need to evaluate numerically.

Comment: More exactly `gamma(x)` is indeed `x * gamma(x-1)`. But there is no simple formula to get the value of gamma between 0 and 1, what you would need to initialize your recurrence...

Comment: I see, but still do you have any references of the integral which I can try to add here?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) is as usual a nice reference. But do not hope it to be simple... As a mere example `gamma(1/2)` is `sqrt(pi)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some different methods to implement the calculation of Gamma Function numerically.
A good one is the Lanczos approximation. The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_approximation) has a [Python implementation example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_approximation#Simple_implementation) which uses some functions from the `math` module, like `sin` or `sqrt`.

You can replace `sqrt(x)` by `x ** (0.5)` in Python.

Rosetta Code has a [Python implementation](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Procedural) based on numerical integration which does not use any method from the `math` module.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain the `_a` tuple with many different floats in the Rosetta Code implementation? Are they predefined gamma function values?

Comment: I think those are pre-calculated coefficients for some asymptotic series that converges to the gamma function. I have found one of such series [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html), on the equation 35, but I have the impression it is not exactly this one that was used (given the `y  = float(x) - 1.0` line).